# Update jQuery version within Telerik MVC Extensions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

I'm currently working on a project that has Telerik MVC Extensions within it.  Recently, we were notified that our version of jQuery (version 1.7.1) was required to be updated to prevent a security risk.  We decided to update to version 3.4.1 (most recent package on NuGet).

However, this has caused an issue within Telerik, seeing how it is tied to version 1.7.1 of jQuery.  There doesn't seem to be an easy way of untangling the two, without modifying libraries, something which I'm not exactly entirely comfortable with.

Is there a way to update the version of jQuery that Telerik MVC Extensions uses?  Our version of Telerik MVC Extensions is 2013.2.611.

Comment: You can't update your telerik version?  Or instead of going to the most recent version, try 1.8 or something older, but newer than 1.7.1.

Comment: Telerik MVC Extensions ended with version 2013.2.611.  We do not have a replacement for it as things stand.  This version was inherited with the project.  The same with jQuery 1.7.1.

However, we wish to update the version of jQuery to 3.4.1.  The only catch so far is Telerik doesn't like this new version due to specific things within jQuery 1.7.1 no longer exist within 3.4.1.

Comment: Yes I forgot it eventually became Kendo and a paid product.  3.4.1 from 1.7.1 is always a big leap for any vendor product so I was suggesting a smaller leap of 1.8 or something closer may still cause the product to work?

Comment: We may try that.  We're mostly looking to update the project so it's not astronomically out of date.  Telerik is one of the items I'd like to update down the road too but jQuery seemed to be lower hanging fruit.  We may try 1.8 first just to see if that has issues.  Thanks.